# Как зайти в MySQL Server в Docker container?

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Собрал образ на основании вот этого Dockerfile:https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/tree/mysql-server/8.0

```
docker build . --tag mysql-image
```

запустил сбилденный mysql image

```
 docker run -it mysql-image /bin/bash
```

запустился.
Попытался войти в mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

запросил пароль - ввел "root" (другого не знаю) -  выдал ошибку:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySql serve through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

Подскажите как зайти в mysql контейнер? Сам только начал изучать Docker.
Сам Dockerfile:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
ARG MYSQL_SERVER_PACKAGE=mysql-community-server-minimal-8.0.22
ARG MYSQL_SHELL_PACKAGE=mysql-shell-8.0.22

# Install server
RUN yum install -y https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-minimal-release-el7.rpm \
      https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7.rpm \
  && yum-config-manager --enable mysql80-server-minimal \
  && yum install -y \
      $MYSQL_SERVER_PACKAGE \
      $MYSQL_SHELL_PACKAGE \
      libpwquality \
  && yum clean all \
  && mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY healthcheck.sh /healthcheck.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
HEALTHCHECK CMD /healthcheck.sh
EXPOSE 3306 33060 33061
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

Файл docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
set -e

echo "[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.22-1.1.18"
# Fetch value from server config
# We use mysqld --verbose --help instead of my_print_defaults because the
# latter only show values present in config files, and not server defaults
_get_config() {
    local conf="$1"; shift
    "$@" --verbose --help 2>/dev/null | grep "^$conf" | awk '$1 == "'"$conf"'" { print $2; exit }'
}

# If command starts with an option, prepend mysqld
# This allows users to add command-line options without
# needing to specify the "mysqld" command
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- mysqld "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'mysqld' ]; then
    # Test that the server can start. We redirect stdout to /dev/null so
    # only the error messages are left.
    result=0
    output=$("$@" --validate-config) || result=$?
    if [ ! "$result" = "0" ]; then
        echo >&2 '[Entrypoint] ERROR: Unable to start MySQL. Please check your configuration.'
        echo >&2 "[Entrypoint] $output"
        exit 1
    fi

    # Get config
    DATADIR="$(_get_config 'datadir' "$@")"
    SOCKET="$(_get_config 'socket' "$@")"

    if [ -n "$MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE" ] || [ -n "console" ]; then
        # Don't touch bind-mounted config files
        if ! cat /proc/1/mounts | grep "etc/my.cnf"; then
            sed -i 's/^log-error=/#&/' /etc/my.cnf
        fi
    fi

    if [ ! -d "$DATADIR/mysql" ]; then
        # If the password variable is a filename we use the contents of the file. We
        # read this first to make sure that a proper error is generated for empty files.
        if [ -f "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="$(cat $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)"
            if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
                echo >&2 '[Entrypoint] Empty MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD file specified.'
                exit 1
            fi
        fi
        if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            echo >&2 '[Entrypoint] No password option specified for new database.'
            echo >&2 '[Entrypoint]   A random onetime password will be generated.'
            MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true
            MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD=true
        fi
        mkdir -p "$DATADIR"
        chown -R mysql:mysql "$DATADIR"

        echo '[Entrypoint] Initializing database'
        "$@" --initialize-insecure
        echo '[Entrypoint] Database initialized'

        "$@" --daemonize --skip-networking --socket="$SOCKET"

        # To avoid using password on commandline, put it in a temporary file.
        # The file is only populated when and if the root password is set.
        PASSFILE=$(mktemp -u /var/lib/mysql-files/XXXXXXXXXX)
        install /dev/null -m0600 -omysql -gmysql "$PASSFILE"
        # Define the client command used throughout the script
        # "SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN=0;" is required for products like group replication to work properly
        mysql=( mysql --defaults-extra-file="$PASSFILE" --protocol=socket -uroot -hlocalhost --socket="$SOCKET" --init-command="SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN=0;")

        if [ ! -z "" ];
        then
            for i in {30..0}; do
                if mysqladmin --socket="$SOCKET" ping &>/dev/null; then
                    break
                fi
                echo '[Entrypoint] Waiting for server...'
                sleep 1
            done
            if [ "$i" = 0 ]; then
                echo >&2 '[Entrypoint] Timeout during MySQL init.'
                exit 1
            fi
        fi

        mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | "${mysql[@]}" mysql
        
        if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="$(pwmake 128)"
            echo "[Entrypoint] GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
        fi
        if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_HOST" ]; then
            ROOTCREATE="ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}';"
        else
            ROOTCREATE="ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'; \
            CREATE USER 'root'@'${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'; \
            GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}' WITH GRANT OPTION ; \
            GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}' WITH GRANT OPTION ;"
        fi
        "${mysql[@]}" <<-EOSQL
            DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user NOT IN ('mysql.infoschema', 'mysql.session', 'mysql.sys', 'root') OR host NOT IN ('localhost');
            CREATE USER 'healthchecker'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'healthcheckpass';
            ${ROOTCREATE}
            FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
        EOSQL
        if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
            # Put the password into the temporary config file
            cat >"$PASSFILE" <<EOF
[client]
password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
EOF
            #mysql+=( -p"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" )
        fi

        if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
            echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\` ;" | "${mysql[@]}"
            mysql+=( "$MYSQL_DATABASE" )
        fi

        if [ "$MYSQL_USER" -a "$MYSQL_PASSWORD" ]; then
            echo "CREATE USER '"$MYSQL_USER"'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '"$MYSQL_PASSWORD"' ;" | "${mysql[@]}"

            if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
                echo "GRANT ALL ON \`"$MYSQL_DATABASE"\`.* TO '"$MYSQL_USER"'@'%' ;" | "${mysql[@]}"
            fi

        elif [ "$MYSQL_USER" -a ! "$MYSQL_PASSWORD" -o ! "$MYSQL_USER" -a "$MYSQL_PASSWORD" ]; then
            echo '[Entrypoint] Not creating mysql user. MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD must be specified to create a mysql user.'
        fi
        echo
        for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
            case "$f" in
                *.sh)  echo "[Entrypoint] running $f"; . "$f" ;;
                *.sql) echo "[Entrypoint] running $f"; "${mysql[@]}" < "$f" && echo ;;
                *)     echo "[Entrypoint] ignoring $f" ;;
            esac
            echo
        done

        # When using a local socket, mysqladmin shutdown will only complete when the server is actually down
        mysqladmin --defaults-extra-file="$PASSFILE" shutdown -uroot --socket="$SOCKET"
        rm -f "$PASSFILE"
        unset PASSFILE
        echo "[Entrypoint] Server shut down"

        # This needs to be done outside the normal init, since mysqladmin shutdown will not work after
        if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD" ]; then
            if [ -z "yes" ]; then
                echo "[Entrypoint] User expiration is only supported in MySQL 5.6+"
            else
                echo "[Entrypoint] Setting root user as expired. Password will need to be changed before database can be used."
                SQL=$(mktemp -u /var/lib/mysql-files/XXXXXXXXXX)
                install /dev/null -m0600 -omysql -gmysql "$SQL"
                if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_HOST" ]; then
                    cat << EOF > "$SQL"
ALTER USER 'root'@'${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}' PASSWORD EXPIRE;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE;
EOF
                else
                    cat << EOF > "$SQL"
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE;
EOF
                fi
                set -- "$@" --init-file="$SQL"
                unset SQL
            fi
        fi

        echo
        echo '[Entrypoint] MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.'
        echo
    fi

    # Used by healthcheck to make sure it doesn't mistakenly report container
    # healthy during startup
    # Put the password into the temporary config file
    touch /healthcheck.cnf
    cat >"/healthcheck.cnf" <<EOF
[client]
user=healthchecker
socket=${SOCKET}
password=healthcheckpass
EOF
    touch /mysql-init-complete
    chown -R mysql:mysql "$DATADIR"
    echo "[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.22-1.1.18"
fi

env MYSQLD_PARENT_PID=$$ "$@"
```

Файл healthcheck.sh:

```
if [ -f /mysql-init-complete ]; # The entrypoint script touches this file
then # Ping server to see if it is ready
  mysqladmin --defaults-extra-file=/healthcheck.cnf ping
else # Initialization still in progress
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `mysqld` не запускается, передавая `bash` в команду запуска `docker run -it mysql-image /bin/bash`, вы тем самым говорите докеру не выполнять `mysqld`, а открыть `bash`. Попробуйте сначала запустить контейнер (без баша), посмотреть логи, если он работает, то тогда пытаться коннектиться. Также вместо того, чтобы собирать самим образ можно воспользоваться уже готовыми.

Comment: Без bash контейнер запускается, проверял через docker ps. Как подключиться к mysql  уже запущенного контейнера?

Comment: Dockerfile писал не сам, а взял по ссылке с оф сайта Docker https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server. А где взять уже собранный образ с mysql не нашел

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir docker exec -it <имя_контейнера или id> /bin/bash

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir а уже готовый, вы можете скачать `docker pull mysql:8` тут инструкция https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: Cпасибо! Это помогло!